# Alt + Space + key in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

How can I create an `Alt + Space + C` shortcut in autohotkey? Alt + Space is `!space` but I don't see how I can add a third key without getting an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `#If` directive (requires AHK_L) in combination with the `GetKeyState()` function:

```
#If GetKeyState("Alt", "p")

Space & c::Traytip,, % a_thishotkey

#If
```

or you can use the `Keywait` command:

```
!space::
keywait, c, d, t0.6
If ErrorLevel
    Traytip,, Alt and space
Else
    Traytip,, Alt space and c
Return
```

This will also trigger an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> outcome after 0.6 seconds if you don't press <kbd>C</kbd>.
If that is undesirable you can write it like this:

```
!space::
keywait, c, d, t0.6
If (!ErrorLevel) {
    Traytip,, Alt space and c
    Sleep, 2000
    Traytip,, % a_thishotkey
} Return
```

`!ErrorLevel` means "not ErrorLevel"