# Capslock + s + m in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

My full goal is to be able to hold down `Capslock + s`, which will convert the keys `uiojklm,.` to work like the 10-key number pad.

So as a first step, I am trying to map `Capslock + s + m` to the number `1`

```
SetCapslockState AlwaysOff

Capslock & s::
keywait, m, d, t0.6
If (!ErrorLevel) {
    SendInput {1}
} Return
```

I based my current code off of the answer here: [Alt + Space + key in autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986814/alt-space-key-in-autohotkey)

When I press `Capslock + s + m`, it prints out `m1`. How do I stop the `m` from printing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution. You MUST have AutoHotKey_L for this to work since the traditional AutoHotKey does not support #if.

```
CapsLock & s::
Flag:=!Flag
If (Flag)
    TrayTip, AutoHotKey, Numpad ON, 1
Else
    TrayTip, AutoHotKey, Numpad OFF, 1
Return

#If (Flag)
    m::Send, 0
    k::Send, 1
#If
```

In the first block you toggle a Flag to True/False with CapsLock + s and you show the status with a traytip, then you define the behaviour of certain keys in the next block. Alternatively you could delete the first block and replace the #if (Flag) line with:

```
#If (GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P") and GetKeyState("s", "P"))
```

**Update:**

Tried the following with varying results. The first (commented out) code does use CapsLock + s, but apparently pressing the s key prevents AutoHotKey from seeing certain other key presses (here the letters n,m,i,o,p worked but j,k,l which are on the same hight/scanline on the keyboard were NOT detected)

```
SetCapsLockState, alwaysoff

/*
Capslock & s::
While, (GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P") and GetKeyState("s", "P"))
{
    Input, MyKey, I L1 T0.5
    TrayTip, Key:, %MyKey%
    if (MyKey = "m")
        Send, 1
    if (MyKey = "i")
        Send, 2
    if (MyKey = "k")
        Send, 3
    if (MyKey = "j")
        Send, 4
    if (MyKey = "o")
        Send, 5
    if (MyKey = "p")
        Send, 6
}
Return
*/
```

Just using CapsLock (also on the same like as j,k,l) worked, but that is not what you wanted.

```
Capslock::
While, (GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P"))
{
    Input, MyKey, I L1 T0.5
    TrayTip, Key:, %MyKey%
    if (MyKey = "m")
        Send, 1
    if (MyKey = "i")
        Send, 2
    if (MyKey = "k")
        Send, 3
    if (MyKey = "j")
        Send, 4
    if (MyKey = "o")
        Send, 5
    if (MyKey = "p")
        Send, 6
}
Return
```

Comment: Oooops, just tested my suggested aternative with #If (GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P") and GetKeyState("s", "P")), and that doesn't work properly (yet).

Comment: That is close to what I'm looking for, but I want the Numpad feature to only work while Capslock & s are held down. (Your example is to toggle)